# Ошибка при создании таблицы

Tags: sql, postgresql

Пытаюсь создать таблицу вот так:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
  id       SERIAL      NOT NULL,
  nick     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  email    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Возникает такая ошибка:

```
[2016-11-21 17:19:13] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "user"
```

Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Слово user зарезервировано, его нельзя использовать для названия таблицы. Можно создать такую таблицу только заключив имя в двойные кавычки. Правда по всех запросах придется так же писать его в кавычках

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reserved words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

User это зарезервированное слово